# Unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, function, class, variables, program-entry-point

This is the error im getting:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'

I have searched for other people with similiar problems, but couldn't quite find anything to similiar to mine. I havent gotten this problem before either.

I want to calculate the total flight time

The problem occurs in this line of code:

```py
def get_total_flight_time(self):

        total_flight_time = 0

        for f in self.flights:

            total_flight_time += f.get_flight_time()


        return total_flight_time
```

Here is the rest of my code for reference

```py
from datetime import datetime

class Flight(object):
    def __init__(self, new_flight_number, new_departure_time, new_arrival_time):
        self.flight_number = None
        self.departure_time = None
        self.arrival_time = None

        self.flight_number = str(new_flight_number)
        self.departure_time = new_departure_time
        self.arrival_time = new_arrival_time

    def get_flight_number(self):
        return self.flight_number

    def get_departure_time(self):
        return self.departure_time
    def set_departure_time(self, new_departure_time):
        self.departure_time = new_departure_time

    def get_arrival_time(self):
        return self.arrival_time
    def set_arrival_time(self, new_arrival_time):
        self.arrival_time = new_arrival_time

    def get_flight_time(self):
        return (self.arrival_time - self.departure_time )

class Itinerary(object):
    def __init__(self, new_flights):
        self.flights = None

        self.flights = new_flights
        
    def get_total_travel_time(self):
        total_travel_time = 0
        if len(self.flights) > 0:
            first_flight_departure = self.flights[0].get_departure_time()
            last_flight_arrival = self.flights[len(self.flights) - 1].get_arrival_time()

            total_travel_time = (last_flight_arrival - first_flight_departure )
        
        return total_travel_time

    def get_total_flight_time(self):

        total_flight_time = 0

        for f in self.flights:

            total_flight_time += f.get_flight_time()


        return total_flight_time


def main():

    flights = []

    flights.append(
        Flight("US230", datetime(2014, 4, 5, 5, 5, 0), 
                        datetime(2014, 4, 5, 6, 15, 0))
    )

    flights.append(
        Flight("US235", datetime(2014, 4, 5, 6, 55, 0), 
                        datetime(2014, 4, 5, 7, 45, 0))
    )

    flights.append(
        Flight("US237", datetime(2014, 4, 5, 9, 35, 0), 
                        datetime(2014, 4, 5, 12, 55, 0))
    )

    itinerary = Itinerary(flights)

    print("Total Travel time: ", itinerary.get_total_travel_time())

    print("Total Flight time: ", itinerary.get_total_flight_time())

main()
```

Comment: Well, `get_flight_time` returns the difference between two datetimes, which is a timedelta instance. Your `total_flight_time`, however, is initially set to 0, which is an `int`. You can't add different types.

Comment: One solution is to set `total_flight_time` also to a timedelta object; by default, it will be zero days/seconds/years/anything. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta . For example, `from datetime import timedelta; total_flight_time = timedelta()`.

Comment: I changed the ```total_flight_time = 0``` to ```total_flight_time = timedelta(seconds=0)```  inside the function ```get_total_flight_time``` and it worked

Comment: @CarlosAdir The `seconds=0` part is not even needed; it is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this exception is since `total_flight_time` (`int`) and `f.get_flight_time()` (returns a `timedelta`) are two different types.

Python does not know how to apply the `+` operand to them. In order to resolve this, you'll want to make sure they are the same type before you add them, namely, either `int` or `datetime.timedelta`.

It seems like you need the number to be a `timedelta` object, so in order to create one with a value of 0, use `timedelta(seconds=0)`, and assign this value to `total_flight_time`.

If you just want to use `int`, you can use `int(f.get_flight_time().total_seconds())` and then later if you need to convert that into a timedelta, you can do so with `timedelta(seconds=`< total seconds >`)`